# Direct image links in webview displaying full size

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am using android webview to wrap a jquery mobile website that is remotely hosted.

Every time I click a link on the site that goes directly to an image the image is displayed in full resolution.  Is there any way to get webview to open the image with picture viewer or at the very least scale the image down to fit the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android webviews have a

```
zoomOut()
```

method